# Cloud 9 IDE Ruby on Rails Already Implemented Coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, cloud9-ide

Okay, so I am new to Ruby, let alone Ruby on Rails. I am using this online IDE called Cloud9 and or other wise known as C9. Anyways once you generate all your files you are given a Coffeescript file. I used this code, however it is not working. I have already installed the package through the node manager. However, when I used the console.log method for testing it did work.

Comment: You need to rework your question. Is it about Cloud9, Coffeescript or a package? FWIW avoid the IDE, just use a text editor to reduce the learning curve to just learning Rails and Coffescript.

Comment: @MattStevens it's mostly a text editor and a terminal linked to a Ubuntu box in the cloud. Apparently recommended by Rails Tutorial (by M. Hartl) to avoid OS-specific problems.

Comment: The question needs a little more detail before anything can be answered. Rails -> CoffeeScript (file is given, by whom?). 'Used this code' (which?), installed the package (which?).

Comment: I had figured it out, the gem had needed to be installed. I had forgotten the = in the .gem.